# What does a two by two union of disjoint sets mean in $A_1, A_2, A_3$, for every pair $i,j \in {1, 2, 3}$ and $i \neq j$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I know the definition of a disjoint set, but it is the first time that I have heard about a two by two union in three sets $A_1, A_2, A_3$ when

$\cap_i^3  A_i$ $=\varnothing$ and $A_i \cup Aj \neq \varnothing$ for every pair $i,j \in ${1, 2, 3} when $i \neq j$

I'm trying to solve it using union A1,A2 and A3 (like {1,2,3} = Ai in a diagram. But what happens with j and its interceptions? What does i != j mean and it's restricted by only three elements? How do I diagram or solve this? j is confusing me...

I'm trying to do it this but I think its wrong.

[image]

(There are very few theories and definitions in books and similar exercises on the Internet: there's nothing only see a very little notation and reference in Herstein...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no element in the sets $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$ at the same time, but there are elements in $A_1$ and $A_2$, in $A_2$ and $A_3$, and in $A_1$ and $A_3$. The associated Venn's diagram would be this one:[image]

Comment: thank you!! i didnt remember the null sets problems!. its all about this.
 
so Ai, represent a set without elements and aj represent the set with elements {1,2,3] intercepted. thank you Fabien

Answer (score 1):

It just means that if you take any pair of $A_1, A_2$ or $A_3$ and look at their intersection is will not be empty.

$A_1 \cap A_2 \ne \emptyset$

$A_1 \cap A_3 \ne \emptyset$

$A_2 \cap A_3 \ne \emptyset$

But $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_2 = \emptyset$

It is okay to write this only with only $3$ sets but what if you had $5$.

You'd have $A_1\cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5$ but

1. $A_1 \cap A_2 \ne \emptyset$
2. $A_1 \cap A_3 \ne \emptyset$
3. $A_1 \cap A_4 \ne \emptyset$
4. $A_1 \cap A_5 \ne \emptyset$
5. $A_2 \cap A_3 \ne \emptyset$
6. $A_2 \cap A_4 \ne \emptyset$
7. $A_2 \cap A_5 \ne \emptyset$
8. $A_3 \cap A_4 \ne \emptyset$
9. $A_3 \cap A_5 \ne \emptyset$
10. $A_4 \cap A_5 \ne \emptyset$

That's too many things to write one after another we need some way to right that *any* pair $A_i$ and $A_j$ that $A_i \cap A_j \ne \emptyset$.

Here's the Venn Diagram for Three such sets

[image]

Doing a Venn diagram of 4 or more would be nearly impossible in only two dimensions.

A practical example is $A_1 \cap A_2 = \{1\}$, $A_1\cap A_3 = \{2\}$ and $A_2 \cap A_3 = \{3\}$ but $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3=\emptyset$ so $A_1 = \{1,2\}$ and $A_2=\{1,3\}$ and $A_2 = \{2,3\}$.